# css: border bottom pushing content out of center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have the `a` tags centered vertically using a flex box model.  When I apply the class `active` to an `a` tag, I want to have a border bottom on it but I want space between it and the content.  I added padding-bottom to it but it also then pushing the `a` tag content out of the center.  How can I accomplish this without moving the `a` tag content out of the center?

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.active {
  color: #111111 !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #111111;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Heavy'
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <img src="">
  <a class="active">Shop</a>
  <a>Orders</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have the `border-bottom` present at all times. But when not `.active`, make it transparent. See my answer in the duplicate for more details.